# ¿Cómo puedo proteger mi código de robo?

Tags: java, android

Soy estudiante de programación y me he enterado de que uno de mis profesores actuales, en este caso de Programación para dispositivos móviles, particularmente Android, hace negocio con los proyectos finales de los alumnos.

Al final del semestre se entrega un proyecto de aplicación móvil, y se entrega el proyecto y todo lo referente a el mismo.

El profesor al tener acceso a el código, lo vende como propio, o lo modifica un poco para el mismo fin, venderlo como aplicación propia.
Algunos compañeros que ya pasaron por eso y lo han confrontado, han dicho que el profesor se defiende con el argumento de que no lo tienen registrado mientras que él sí, y no hay manera de que los alumnos puedan hacer algo contra él en ese momento.

Eso es el origen de mi pregunta, de si es posible preveer esto de alguna manera y evitar que el profesor pueda robar las aplicaciones mías o de mis compañeros. y en caso de hacerlo, cómo podemos defendernos ante ello y como menos, conseguir algo de reconocimiento o retribución por el trabajo.

Comment: se me ocurre que solo le entreguen el APK.

Comment: o el link de descarga de la tienda :P

Comment: Acciona legalmente contra él. La ley de propiedad intelectual está escrita para defender los derechos del autor. Si tienes forma de probar que entregaste la aplicación como un proyecto y el profesor lo robó, el hecho de que el profesor lo haya registrado a su nombre, lejos de favorecerlo, regularmente solo empeora su situación, pues en la mayoría de las legislaciones eso es considerado un delito y conlleva penas de cárcel, no solo administrativas o económicas.

Comment: Si tu profesor hace dinero vendiendo aplicaciones de móvil hechas como proyectos finales de los alumnos, entonces es un genio absoluto de ventas. Mi consejo: es bastante probable que esto sean habladurías, y aun si no sean, no pierdas el tiempo en ofuscar código o pretender una remuneración. Si tienes evidencias firmes, entonces denuncialo a tu universidad.

Comment: solo haz la validacion del programa mediante un servidor, el cual contenga la mayoria de las funcionalidades, Asi entregarias solo el codigo de la app android.
el mismo seria inutil sin el servidor.

Comment: Habría que ver de donde es, porque en México no existe en las obras de software eso de la "propiedad intelectual", por ejemplo yo puedo escribir un clon de otro software, idéntico, pero si no usé su código, no hay cargo alguno. El derecho de autor mexicano protege la obra, no la idea. En ese caso valdría registrar con el Instituto Nacional de Derecho de Autor su código antes de entregarlo al profesor.

Answer (score 10):

Extracto de [Preguntas frecuentes prácticas universitaras](http://www.javeriana.edu.co/rectoria/faqs-practicas-universitarias) de la Pontificia Universidad Javeriana de Bogotá :

> En consecuencia, las obras realizadas por los estudiantes, en
>   desarrollo de una práctica de carácter universitario, les pertenece,
>   son ellos quienes tendrán la calidad de autor. En caso que la entidad
>   desee apropiarse de la titularidad de las obras desarrolladas por los
>   estudiantes, deberá suscribir, con el estudiante autor, un contrato de
>   cesión de derechos en el que se deberá indicar como mínimo los
>   siguientes aspectos: identificación de las partes, definición del
>   objeto, alcance de la cesión, determinación si la misma es a título
>   gratuito u oneroso y duración de la cesión. Adicionalmente, dicho
>   contrato deberá constar en escritura pública o en instrumento privado
>   reconocido ante notario.

Donde estudié yo, en la Universidad de Alicante, también hay normativa similar al respecto. Y seguramente también la haya en la institución en que estudias.

Esta es una cuestión de ética y de relación alumno-profesor. No es una cuestión de programación. El uso de ofuscadores de código u otras triquiñuelas no es una solución. Un alumno normalmente desea que su tutor tenga total acceso a su código pues de esta manera podrá guiarle mejor en su aprendizaje.

En este caso el profesor actúa de forma inmoral y, probablemente, ilegal. Mi consejo es :

- Abandona ese profesor si te es posible. No es un buen maestro.
- No le confrontes directamente sobre este asunto. Y mucho menos si no te ha evaluado y necesitas aprobar su curso.
- Si te es imprescindible seguir con su curso tienes dos opciones.

  - Pedir consejo a alguien en quien tengas máxima confianza de confidencialidad. Si hay un defensor del alumno en tu institución empezaría por ahí. Nunca actúes solo y nunca desde la ignorancia.
  - Agachar la cabeza y seguir. La vida está llena de situaciones injustas y hay que saber elegir qué batallas luchar.

Comment: +1 por poner las cosas en su lugar ("no es una cuestión de programacion") y por desaconsejar "ofuscadores y otras triquiñuelas" .

Comment: - 1000 (???) =\  No había leído este post!, "Abandona ese profesor si te es posible. No es un buen maestro." ?! Creo que un proyecto en una escuela es diferente a la vida real en una empresa. De hecho si realizas un proyecto en una empresa lo derechos son de la empresa (las empresas deben tener acotada esta regla en sus contratos). Hay respuestas como esta que he visto al instante son llenadas con -1 ...  En fín lo que haré será: "Agachar la cabeza y seguir. La vida está llena de situaciones injustas y hay que saber elegir qué batallas luchar." =)

Comment: @Elenasys Ni -1000 ni -1. [Tu no has votado negativo en esta respuesta](http://i.imgur.com/5qj7VYD.png)

Answer (score 2):

Lo mismo le ocurrío a un amigo mío. Su solución fue entregar un código diferente al que el ejecutaba así una vez se lo enviaba y lo presentaba en la memoria este no se ejecutaba.

Frente a profesores más listos y hábiles que éste, obviamente la mayoría correran el programa y verán si funciona antes de perderte la pista...

Yo aconsejo registrar tu programa como propiedad intelectual, infórmate, suele costar un poco de dinero y quizás si no vas a ofrecerlo como producto tuyo no merezca la pena.

Importante: los trabajos con las universidades comúnmente no solo son propiedad intelectual del alumno, está la firma del coordinador y como tal es coautor, no soy nada partidario de esto, pero sin ser abogado como mucho podrás reclamar tu parte si demuestras que se ha beneficiado monetariamente.

Revisa en secretaria el marco legal de trabajo en el proyecto y si te es favorable de alguna manera, tienes que informar a tu profesor de la actividad ilegal que supone y emprender alguna acción legal o acuerdo amistoso.

Para todos los demás supuestos en el que no hay pruebas ni elementos legales que te acrediten como autor, solo estarás perdiendo el tiempo, muy valioso que con talento se hace un APK mejor.

Comment: Otra forma de generar evidencias de que X proyecto te pertenece, en algunas  universidades manejan una " incubadora de proyectos" ahí puede registrar su aplicación y documentar su funcionamiento. De tal forma que el profesor no pueda usarlo sinicamente.

Comment: Correcto si la universidad facilita esa herramienta sería muy interesante. Eso sí, ciertos profesores se abstendrian de tutorizar correctamente los proyectos ya que no conllevan ningun beneficio personal( lo se es su labor como docente pero ellos lo ven asi..). En mi caso no hice un programa, hice una buena investigacion que la incluyo en su propio trabajo, dentro del mundo universitario considero que hay que bajarse algo mas los pantalones y cooperar a pesar de que te roben las ideas pero de alguna manera todos salimos ganando.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo puedo proteger mi código de robo?

El código ofuscado hace que por medio de tu APK sea difícil obtener el código a través de ingeniería inversa, la ofuscación de es especialmente valiosa cuando tu aplicación utiliza datos sensibles dentro del código, como la verificación de licencias.

Para ofuscar tu código en una aplicación android regularmente se usa [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android) (aunque existen otras opciones).

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android

> Google's dx compiler converts ordinary jar files into files that run
> on Android devices. By preprocessing the original jar files, ProGuard
> can significantly reduce the file sizes and boost the run-time
> performance of the code.

Tal vez recuerdas el archivo que se generaba en la raíz del proyecto, [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android) además de ofuscar ayudaba a optimizar el .apk generalmente reducia el tamaño del archivo y por supuesto lo mantenía ofuscado.

Actualmente el archivo y las opciones para ProGuard se definen en el build.gradle

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Este tutorial me parece muy completo para que puedas configurar tu proyecto Android con ofuscación:

**[Uso de Proguard para ofuscar una aplicación Android.](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-avanzado/48-unidad-9-ingenieria-inversa-en-android/348-ofuscacion-del-codigo)**

#### Es importante saber que desgraciadamente no hay método infalible para evitar una ingeniería inversa.

Comment: Es un trabajo de estudiante. El profesor necesita el código para evaluar al alumno. Si entregas el apk ofuscado y no entregas el código fuente te suspenden. Esta respuesta no solo no soluciona el problema que se plantea sino que además empeora la situación.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, lo considero fuera de lugar, la pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo proteger mi código de robo?, ¿empeora la situación?, estas hablando de otro asunto, si alguien necesita ver el código de tu trabajo o tu escuela simplemente, tu crees que lo tendría que revisar el .APK, es fuera de lugar tu comentario.

Comment: La pregunta es acerca de un estudiante que entrega un trabajo a un profesor para ser evaluado. Un estudiante que siga tu consejo será suspendido. Eso es objetivamente malo para el estudiante.

Comment: **Los temas de los que se habla en Stackoverflow deberían ser estrictamente de desarrollo IT, no de cuestiones someras o éticas.** "Si entregas el apk ofuscado y no entregas el código fuente te suspenden", tu crees que en todos los lugares los usuarios entregan  un .apk o adhoc? "si entregas el .apk ofuscado te suspenden" que raro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si bien es cierto proteger el código no hay forma de hacerlo tal vez 100%, lo que si es que puedes usar técnicas de ofuscación de  código. En tu proyecto como lo mencionan solo puedes entregar el apk. Referente a los fuentes, entrégalo con algún cifrado fuerte de tal forma que al menos le cueste unos días  hacerle  un bypass.

[Java ofuscación](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)

[Ofuscación Técnicas](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/JBCO/examples.html)

Comment: Ofuscar != proteger. Ofuscar solo hace el código menos legible, pero a final de cuentas se puede leer y entender (lleva más tiempo, solo eso).

Comment: Es correcto, lo vuelve un poco más complejo de entender, como el compañero comenta que sus proyectos son  alterados para hacerse de los créditos y por lo que imagino lucrar con ellos para su propio beneficio, al menos le costara un poco más y no será el copy and remplace.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el codigo sea ilegible/dificil de interpretar, puedes utilizar tecnicas de ofuscacion. Entregando solo el apk también le peude llevar varios dias sacar el codigo fuente, pero hay herramientas para hacerlo, no funcionan al 100% pero son bastante decentes.

Como experiencia personal, hice un proyecto con angular y ADF para mi final de carrera, lo que hice fue modificar el codigo fuente de angular cuando inicializaba la aplicacion y enviar una request a un webservice para verificar si se estaba usando, y ofuscarlo otra vez. Este metodo tampoco es 100% fiable, pero te permitiria saber si alguien lo utiliza, y pararlo en caso que quieras. Pero alguien con tiempo se puede dar cuenta.

Comment: Puede indicar un ejemplo de omo realizabas eso?? Es bastante interesante @JorgeDePedroMartin

Comment: Angular es un framework de javascript, del cual te puedes descargar el codigo fuente completo. En la funcion donde se inicializaba el framework, enviaba un timestamp codificaco con un cifrado md5, que el webservice recibia y respondia de manera correcta, salvo que yo lo modificara para bloquear la aplicacion. Si la respuesta era un codigo 200, el codigo seguia sin problemas, si no terminaba. El webservice lo puedes hacer con distintas tecnologias, como mas rabia te de, yo en cualquier caso utilizaria Apache CXF que es bastante sencillo, ya que usas java.