# Seguridad en App Android

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, seguridad

Estoy terminando la 1ª app que he desarrollado, la cual maneja datos sensibles y cualquier modificación o alteración de los datos o del manejo de los mismos puede causar grandes daños a la infraestructura de la empresa.

Tengo miedo de que Apps del tipo xMod puedan terminar destrozando el funcionamiento de esta app.

> ¿Algún consejo sobre como evitar que terceros puedan descompilar el
>   código o acceder a mi base de datos en el servidor ?

Comment: Hola Djya Web, te recomiendo leer [ask] y revisar en el sitio si lo que preguntas ya se realizo anteriormente. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22333/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-proteger-mi-c%C3%B3digo-de-robo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo proteger mi código de robo?

En una aplicación Android, el código ofuscado hace que por medio de tu .APK, sea "difícil" obtener el código a través de ingeniería inversa, la ofuscación es especialmente valiosa cuando tu aplicación utiliza datos sensibles dentro del código, como la verificación de licencias.

Para ofuscar tu código en una aplicación android regularmente se usa [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android) (aunque existen otras opciones).

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#android

> Google's dx compiler converts ordinary jar files into files that run
>   on Android devices. By preprocessing the original jar files, ProGuard
>   can significantly reduce the file sizes and boost the run-time
>   performance of the code.

Agrego un tutorial para configurar tu proyecto Android con ofuscación:

[Uso de Proguard para ofuscar una aplicación Android.](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-avanzado/48-unidad-9-ingenieria-inversa-en-android/348-ofuscacion-del-codigo)

**Es importante saber que desgraciadamente no hay método infalible para evitar una ingeniería inversa.**

Answer (score 1):

Encripta tu información con metodos como SHA-1 como tal el proceso que se genera en tu apk (LOGINCA DE NEGOCIOS)la puedes ocultar por medio de multiples clases aunque poco recomendable ya que se generan muchos archivos aunque a la hora de realizar la ingeneria inversa te quedaria algo asi 
[image: APK con ingeneria inversa]

Ya con esto es por lo menos mas complicado para el que hace la ingeneria inversa lo hace mas complicado identificar todos los flujos de tu apk.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente no puedes evitar la ingeniería inversa.
Tienes que evitar dejar datos que puedan ser utilizados por terceros dentro de la aplicación.
Si tienes la necesidad, tendrás que guardarlos cifrados y descifrarlos una vez autenticado el usuario.
Puedes identificar el dispositivo que quiere acceder al servidor y bloquearlo si no esta autorizado o ha sido dado de baja por robo, por ejemplo.
Si usas "proveedores de contenido" (ContentProviders) Marca en el manifest android:exported=false esto evita que se comparta datos con otras aplicaciones.
Si usas el "almacenamiento interno" Android solo le da acceso a los datos a tu aplicacion.
También Android te permite cifrar el sistema de archivos del dispositivo. Saludos.
Usa Proguard.